# How to apply data governance to API integration

Tags: api, integration, data-integration, data-governance

I'm new to data governance/API integration, forgive me if the questions lacks some information.

We have an Application integration team who will integrate some applications together. For example, an application create some data in its application database and this data should be loaded into another application's database and then run some stored procedures, so no API calls.

My question is here:

- who should do the integration? application integration team or data integration team.
- what's the difference between application integration/data integration?

Can governance be applied to this scenario? We're using Apache Atlas. should we govern this process in atlas? We usually use atlas to govern data in ETLs/data pipelines. Is it best practice to govern data in Application-Application Integration?